# Placing plain text input in an AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

How to place plain text input in an AlertDialog?

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Enter The Subject Name");
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Subject Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    Dialog dialog = builder.create();
    return dialog;
}
```

Comment: As for the first part of your question, kindly add more context on what you are doing and what's not working. The second part of your question is not within the scope of any SE site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the setView method of the AlertDialog.Builder. You can create an xml layout that includes the edittext and then set it as the view of your dialog:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/myEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>
```

And then you can use

```
final View customLayout = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.edittext, null);
builder.setView(customLayout);

Dialog dialog = builder.create();
EditText editText = (EditText) customLayout.findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
editText.setText("Editable text");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
exitByBackKey(); // call in main class

//Custom Dialog Java file
public void exitByBackKey() {

        tableDialog = new Dialog(DashBoardActivity.this);
        tableDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        tableDialog.setContentView(R.layout.exit_dialog);
        tableDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        Window window = tableDialog.getWindow();
        lp.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());
        lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        window.setAttributes(lp);

        tableDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tableDialog.setCancelable(true);
        tableDialog.show();
    enter code here
        CustomTextView txtMessage = (CustomTextView) tableDialog
                .findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
        `enter code here`CustomButton btnDialogOk = (CustomButton) tableDialog
                .findViewById(R.id.btnAlertOk);
        CustomButton btnDialogcancel = (CustomButton) tableDialog
                .findViewById(R.id.btnAlertCancel);
        txtMessage.setText("Do you want to stop this Application?");
        btnDialogOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tableDialog.dismiss();
                DashBoardActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
        btnDialogcancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tableDialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
    }

//Xml File of custom Dialog  exit_dialog.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/header_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <innovify.hustl.library.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ABC"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <innovify.hustl.library.CustomButton
            android:id="@+id/btnAlertOk"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#e2e2e2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Ok" />

        <innovify.hustl.library.CustomButton
            android:id="@+id/btnAlertCancel"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#e2e2e2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```